# Nginx redirect from old domain to new with ssl

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, redirect

I am trying to change the domain name for my site from `https://www.myolddomain.se/` to `https://www.mynewdomain.se/`

The problem is that for my old domain I forced SSL on all pages and therefore all links on google and other sites are linked with https. When I try to visit the old domain from an https link I get a certificate error. So my question is: how can I redirect all pages linked with https to another https secured domain, in nginx, without getting this error?

I did some research and found this solution for redirecting web pages, which is now inserted in my config file. Though I still get the certificate error!

```
server {
        server_name .myolddomain.se;
        return 301 https://www.mynewdomain.se$request_uri;
}
```

But I just can't get it to work! If anyone could come up with an answer I would be very grateful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution depends on client capabilities, your budget and architecture specificities.

**1. If both domains are hosted on the same IP address and you can't have an other one :**

If client supports TLS SNI extension :

```
server {
    listen X.X.X.X:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/myolddomain.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/myolddomain.key;
    server_name .myolddomain.se;
    return 301 https://www.mynewdomain.se$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen X.X.X.X:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/mynewdomain.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/mynewdomain.key;
    server_name .mynewdomain.se;

    [ ... ] # Your stuff

}
```

If it doesn't but understands x509 extension `SubjectAltName` and you can afford to generate a new certificate then ask for a unique certificate for both domains. The configuration should look like :

```
server {
    listen X.X.X.X:443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/domain.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/domain.key;
    server_name _;
}

server {
    listen X.X.X.X:443;
    server_name .myolddomain.se;
    return 301 https://www.mynewdomain.se$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen X.X.X.X:443;
    server_name .mynewdomain.se;

    [ ... ] # Your stuff

}
```

**2. If each domain is on a distinct IP address or if it's on the same but you can have another one**

The most generic solution, listen on two different IPs (usually an additional public IP is "simply" an option to purchase at your hosting provider) :

```
server {
    listen X.X.X.X:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/myolddomain.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/myolddomain.key;
    server_name .myolddomain.se;
    return 301 https://www.mynewdomain.se$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen Y.Y.Y.Y:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/mynewdomain.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/mynewdomain.key;
    server_name .mynewdomain.se;

    [ ... ] # Your stuff

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer worked perfectly for me, and I could not have wished for a more thorough one. I am very grateful, thanks!