# Redirect NGINX HTTPS domain to new HTTPS domain

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

After spending hours using duckduckgo, this was the best answer I arrived at and it's still not working to redirect a currently HTTPS domain to a new HTTPS domain.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.olddomain.com olddomain.com;
    rewrite 301 https://newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Browser gives Insecure Connection error.

I have also tried things like

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name olddomain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/OLD.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/OLD.key;

    #enables all versions of TLS, but not SSLv2 or 3 which are weak and now deprecated.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_ciphers "ALLLLLLTTHHISSSS";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    rewrite 301 https://newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Although this option stops giving an error the rewrite is not working and it goes to a "Welcome to NGINX Page."

Comment: `return 301` not rewrite.  SSL connects first, you need a valid SSL even to redirect... Look at letsencrypt

Answer (score 3):

If you want to redirect https requests from an old to a new domain name you'll need a certificate for the old website configured inside that Nginx server block.

You'll need to cater for https://example.com and https://www.example.com

This is a basic config that should do the job. IMHO you don't need to worry about SSL versions for a server that just does forwarding, just use the defaults.

```
server {    
  server_name www.example.com;    

  listen 443 ssl;    

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/fullchain;    
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/certs/***CERT_DIRECTORY/privkey;    

  return 301 https://www.example2.com$request_uri;          
}
```

Comment: This will give Cert Error if 
1. the domains are on the same host/IP
2. the certs don't support both the old and new domain

The only way the above may work is if the old domain is on a different IP/Host to the new one. 

For a solution that works with the first scenario see this: https://serverfault.com/questions/633168/nginx-redirect-from-old-domain-to-new-with-ssl

Comment: This works across domains on my own server. I haven't tried cross servers so you may be correct.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to redirect an entire domain, I usually just forward the domain at the domain name registrar level. Here's [how to forward your domain](https://www.godaddy.com/help/forward-a-domain-12123) if you're using GoDaddy. Most registrars will allow you to do this.

**Benefits of setting forwarding at registrar level:**

- You don't have to worry about getting things right on your server
- You won't accidentally forget to set up your Apache (or other web server) redirects if you move to a new server

**Drawbacks to server-level forwarding:**

- Less control if you're just forwarding say port 80 but not 443

Sometimes the simplest answer is best... took me a while to think of this the first time :)

Comment: I don't think using registrar specific solutions is a great idea.

Comment: @tim, can you provide your specifics on why registrar forwards are not a good idea? I already noted some of them but will add more if they are not just personal preference.

Comment: Vendor specific solutions can create unexpected and difficult to solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 301 redirect on the new domain from http to https you can avoid the certificate problem by redirecting from the old-domain to the http version of the new domain. eg:

On the old domain

```
server {
    server_name old-domain.com www.old-domain.com;
    return 301 http://new-domain.com/$request_uri;
}
```

On the new domain

```
server {
    listen 80
    server_name new-domain.com www.new-domain.com;
    return 301 https://new-domain.com/$request_uri;
}
```